# How can I select nearby search results when using Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am building an iOS map with local search functionality similar to Yelp.

The user will see a local map generated from Google Maps SDK from iOS, and local points of interest returned by the search, will be displayed on the map as custom markers. Simultaneously, the user can also see these same local search results in a list form on another screen.

My issue is as follows: to optimize loading time, I would like the app to load only the search results within the area displayed by the map, given the coordinates of the center of the map, and the zoom level. This would be more efficient than loading, say, all search results within a 30 km radius, most of which may not be visible on the map. Is there a simple way to know exactly what are the coordinates of the area displayed by the map on the user's phone (bottom left corner, top right corner)?

I have seen other posts online, explaining how the coordinates of the area can be calculated using zoom level, latitude, and screen resolution. However I am wondering if there is a simpler way commonly used by other apps that display local points of interest.

Thank you!